# When exactly *must* an app include the Reachability class to test for network reachability?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, reachability, cfnetwork

According to [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/network-data-requirements-on-iphone-os.html) Reachability is needed when an app requires WiFi (rather than cellular network), e.g. if app loads heavy videos and is not meant to be used over 3G.

My app uses internet no matter if WiFi or 3G and only downloads small data from web services.

Can someone clarify under which circumstances an app must do this reachability test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability is needed if your application needs to know 'when' it's ability to access the network has changed.

I've seen recommendations that say to always try to access your resource first, and if you fail - to use data from Reachability to find out why.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I will do because otherwise i get a heart attack.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using internet connection only for small data downloads you really don't need to care if you're using WiFi or 3G.

True, there are some restrictions for cellular newtorks. Take a look at paragraphs 9.3 and 9.4 [AppStore Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). You need a developer id to view it so i think we're not allowed to quote it here.

Comment: OK so if my app just calls a web service and receives a tiny XML once a day then I don't have to worry about using Apples Reachability class to test reachability?

Comment: @ProudMember: true, you don't need to. Of course you need to be able to handle errors when there would be no internet connectivity at all (or when the host isn't reachable - isn't up) but as far as checking if you're on WiFi or 3G - it doesn't matter in your case.